# How to address a formal letter to a group of women

Tags: business-language, letter-writing

How do you address a formal letter to a group of women - i.e. the equivalent of Dear Sirs, for women?

Comment: *Ladies* comes to mind; *Dear Ladies* or *My Dear Ladies* if you prefer.  Traditional writing often used *Dear Sir or Madam* so *Dear Madams* is correct although I think people avoid it today after that famous speech from the play *I am not a Madam!* which played on the occasional usage of this word for a woman who runs a house of prostitution.  You can address one specifically the rest as a group like *Dear Mrs. Smith and your fellow sewing group members*  You can address the group:  *Dear Daughters of the American Revolution members*.  In what way are these women a group?

Comment: I shudder at 'Dear Ladies' or 'Dear Madams',  but if I had to choose to be included in one it would be the former. If I was one of the people to be included in the address I would prefer, as @Brillig suggests, the use of the group name or descriptor and failing that, 'Dear all'.

Comment: I think it is traditional even in Anglophone contexts to resort to French on the rather rare occasions when pluralizing such ordinary courtesy titles becomes necessary; at least it is an option. The masculine plural *Messieurs* can be abbreviated *Messrs.*--an uncommon but available plural for the abbreviated English courtesy title *Mr.*--but I confess I know no such abbreviation for the feminine plural *Mesdames* (which carries no discernible implication of bawdry).

Comment: @BrianDonovan: though you are right, and you might write a letter to Mesdames Smith, Jones and Green, *Dear Mesdames* is not workable.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - I don't like "Attention."  It gives me the same feeling as an email message in all caps.  Normally, "Attention: Mary Sue" would go on a fax or an envelope, if you are sending a letter to an office or department, and you want the letter to land directly on Mary Sue's desk.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - So now we don't provide feedback on each other's contributions?

Answer (score 1):

If the group has a function or better yet a name, use it.  Such as Dear league of women voters or Dear members of {name of group}.

Comment: I don't think "Dear League of Women Voters" works well in a formal letter.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to specify gender, and would suggest, in the case that you don't know the people you are writing to:

> Dear friends:

In the U.S. I don't think it would feel too informal to address letters this way, unless it were a legal matter or there were a contentious, adversarial tone to the communication.

However, if "Dear friends" does feel too informal for you, here are some alternatives:

> Mesdames:

or

> Good morning [afternoon],

This is a nice trick with a formal group email, and I don't see why it wouldn't work in a business letter format.

Now, since *Dear sir or madam* is technically addressed to a single person, but it works for a group, you could follow that pattern, and address your letter to a single female person:

> Dear madam:

Which follows the old-fashioned pattern of

> Dear sir:

These would only be used if you don't have a *name* to address the letter to.

If you need to address a letter to a clearly defined group, there are already Q&As about that here; let me know if you want me to hunt one down.

Comment: Friends for a formal letter? And if you didn't know them personally? Dear All, is neutral and less intimate in my opinion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I expanded the answer. // My personal opinion about "Dear all" is that it's acceptable but more informal a style.

Answer (score -1):

I think "Dear Madams" is still fine (it's akin to "sirs").  If they are colleagues of yours, I've seen people begin with "Dear colleagues," or "Colleagues,".